# Can not connect LWC and fullCalendar v5

Tags: lightning-web-components, fullcalendar

I am trying to use [fullCalendar v5](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals) library in LWC but I couldn't make it work :(

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import calendarResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendar5';

export default class Calendar extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, calendarResource + '/lib/main.js'),
            loadStyle(this, calendarResource + '/lib/main.css')
        ]).then(() => {
            try {
                var ele = this.template.querySelector('.calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(ele, {});
                calendar.render();
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error calendar init', error);
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error promise all', error);
        });
    }
}
```

Library is being imported successfully but when I'm trying to build calendar (new FullCalendar.Calendar) it says **ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined**

In VFP everything is working good:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullcalendar5 + '/lib/main.js'}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.fullcalendar5 + '/lib/main.css'}"/>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Calendar</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
            <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="calendar"></div>

            <script>
                var ele = document.querySelector('.calendar');
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(ele, {});
                calendar.render();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone help to make it working properly?

Comment: Probably you need to load all the dependent scripts files.

Comment: Do you get the error at compile time or at run time?

Comment: @rahulgawale I did as in documentation plus there is only one script **main.js**, and when I do it in simple HTML, I mean test it in locale desktop, it works.

Comment: @SanderdeJong I get this error at run time. I also tried to do it in Aura and it doesn't work, but in VFP everything is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really **V5** is not working with neither with AURA and LWC.

**V4** is working but has a bug when you hover over the calendar, to fix it I did small workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4990#issuecomment-523291222)

After this fix I am able to create a calendar and for now all fullCalendar features are working good in LWC.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make fullcalendar v5 work in lwc just now.

Your component code is fine, you need to use the already built library and convert main.js to UMD format.

So in main.js you need to change the first line

```
var FullCalendar = (function (exports) {
```

To this

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? 
factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.FullCalendar = {}));
}(this, function (exports) {
```

And then on the elementClosest method change the return statement to el.closest.

```
function elementClosest(el, selector) {
    //return closestMethod.call(el, selector);
    return el.closest(selector);
}
```

I haven't tested if all features work, but at least it loads without errors.

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach, but I was getting the below error :

_Error occured on FullCalendarCmp :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at addDefs (main.js:5556)
    at addDefs (main.js:5560)
    at buildPluginHooks (main.js:5566)
    at CalendarDataManager.eval [as buildPluginHooks] (main.js:5577)
    at CalendarDataManager.processRawCalendarOptions (main.js:7323)
    at CalendarDataManager._computeOptionsData (main.js:7296)
    at CalendarDataManager.eval [as computeOptionsData] (main.js:1082)
    at new CalendarDataManager (main.js:7128)_

Comment: Were you also facing the same issue ? How can we resolve this ?

Comment: Hi @Federico Giust Which version of fullCalendar were you using for this? e.g. 5.xx ? Thanks!

Comment: It was version 5

Comment: @FedericoGiust answer is missing crucial mod at the last line... Here's fully working lib with mod: https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/08b0ae2aebffe5c4c36ffd37d3c8d416

Answer (score 0):

For some reason v4 and v5 are not rendering in lwc component. I am able to achieve it using v3 and you can refer this.
Also you need to load dependent files such as jquery and moment js.

Full demo is here:

FullCalendar - v3 -
https://auraenabled.com/2020/07/fullcalendar-in-lightning-web-component/

Comment: Thanks, I tried v4 and it works for me with small workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4990#issuecomment-523291222)

Answer (score 0):

So that you know, this version of FullCalendar works fine with [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro) (becoming GA for LWC only in Spring).

Comment: That's an org-wide setting tho, right? So it might enable FullCalendar, but break remaining of your org...? :D

Comment: Take into account we're increasing the number of use cases that are supported by loosening the restrictions (while keeping components secure) so, I'd try it. Also bear in mind it's a GA feature - for LWC only! If you've got aura components then my recommendation is to wait for it to be GA for aura too.

Answer (score 0):

**Somewhat** works by improving [Federico's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/315612/3196), example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/08b0ae2aebffe5c4c36ffd37d3c8d416)

As Alba said, works great with LWS.

With old locker in renders initially ok, but Previous/Next buttons break it.