# can not connect salesforce LWC and fullCalendar V5

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, fullcalendar

I know that this question has already been asked here - [stackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313728/can-not-connect-lwc-and-fullcalendar-v5)

The change which has been suggested, in the fullCalendar library is I think already has been implemented in it by FullCalendar Developers. Check the code snippets -

```
193  // Querying
194  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
195  function elementClosest(el, selector) {
196    if (el.closest) {
197        return el.closest(selector);
198        // really bad fallback for IE
199        // from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
200    }
201    if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) {
202        return null;
203    }
204    do {
205        if (elementMatches(el, selector)) {
206            return el;
207        }
208        el = (el.parentElement || el.parentNode);
209    } while (el !== null && el.nodeType === 1);
210    return null;
211  }
```

But even after trying with the solution mentioned in the post and many other solution, I'm still facing the challenge to run the fullCalendar library.

I have also enabled Lightning Web Security, as mentioned in the blog post - [getridbug](https://getridbug.com/salesforce/can-not-connect-lwc-and-fullcalendar-v5/)

---

I'm trying to use FullCalendar library [v5.11.0](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v5.11.0) with LWC

HTML Code (fullCalendarLWC.html)

```
<template>
   this is calendar
   <div id='calendar'></div>
</template>
```

XML Code (fullCalendarLWC.js-meta.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
      <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
   </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

JS Code (fullCalendarLWC.js)

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import fullcalendarJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendar';
import luxonJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/luxon';
import luxonConnectorJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/luxonConnector';
import fullcalendarCss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullcalendarCss';

export default class fullCalendarLWC extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        loadScript(this, fullcalendarJS)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Loaded fullcalendar');
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log('error----'+error));

        loadScript(this, luxonJS)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Loaded luxonJS');
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log('luxonJS error----'+error));

        loadScript(this, luxonConnectorJS)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Loaded luxonConnectorJS');
                console.log(FullCalendar);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log('luxonConnectorJS error----'+error));

        loadStyle(this, fullcalendarCss)
            .then(() => console.log('Loaded fullcalendarCss'))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

        
        // not using this set of code, until Fullcalendar is loaded properly.
        /*var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            headerToolbar: { 
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            timeZone: 'Australia/Darwin',
            //initialDate: '2022-04-07',
            firstDay: 1,
            weekNumbers: true, // show week numbers
            navLinks: true,
            displayEventTime: true, // display the start time
            displayEventEnd: true, // display the end time
            eventTimeFormat: { hour: "numeric", minute: "2-digit", timeZoneName: "short" },
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2022-05-11T14:30:00',
                    extendedProps: {
                    status: 'done'
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2022-05-13T07:00:00',
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    borderColor: 'green'
                }
            ]
        });
        calendar.render();*/
    }
}
```

Lightning App, in which this LWC is called (fullCalendarApp.app)

```
<aura:application >
   <c:fullCalendarLWC />
</aura:application>
```

Getting Following error in Dev Console --

> ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar is likely not getting added to the global namespace in your error. Try changing the first line of the FullCalendar v5.11 module as suggested [by Federico](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/315612/63090). Also [see this pull request in the lwc-recipes repo for the fix](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/pull/655/files) where a similar approach is used on the minified file.

**Replace this**

```js
var FullCalendar = (function (exports) {
```

**With this**

```js
 window.FullCalendar = (function (exports) {
```