# FullCalendar LWC doesn't work on the Lightning Experience site page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, fullcalendar

I've implemented FullCalendar v.5 (from FullCalendar.io) into my LWC. On the home-, record- or other pages inside the Salesforce platform it works well, but my LWC doesn't work on the Lightning Experience site and throws an error - `ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined`. Google searches have not yielded any results and now I am at the dead end.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Here is my code:

**EventsCalendar.js**

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import FullCalendarJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fullCalendar';

import getCalendarEvents from '@salesforce/apex/EventsCalendarController.getCalendarEvents';

export default class EventsCalendar extends LightningElement {
  @track allEvents = [];
  @track selectedEvent = undefined;

  CALENDAR_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Error occured on FullCalendarJS';
  TIMEZONE_VARIANT = 'local';
  fullCalendarJsInitialised = false;

 renderedCallback() {

    if (this.fullCalendarJsInitialised) {
      return;
    }

    this.fullCalendarJsInitialised = true;

    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, FullCalendarJS + '/main.js'),
      loadStyle(this, FullCalendarJS + '/main.css'),
    ])
    .then(() => {
      this.getAllEvents();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error({
        message: this.CALENDAR_ERROR_MESSAGE,
        error
      });
    })
  }

  initialiseFullCalendarJs() {
    const calendarElement = this.template.querySelector('div.fullcalendarjs');

    const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
      customButtons : {
        newEventButton : {
          text : 'New Event',
          click : () => this.newEventClickHandler()
        }
      },
      headerToolbar : {
        left: 'prev,next newEventButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
      },
      businessHours:   {
        daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        startTime: '09:00',
        endTime: '18:00'
      },
      firstDay: 1,
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: new Date(),
      nowIndicator: true,
      selectable: false,
      navLinks : true,
      editable : true,
      events : this.allEvents,
      dragScroll : true,
      droppable : false,
      weekNumbers : false,
      dayMaxEvents: true,
      dateClick : this.dayClickHandler.bind(this),
      eventClick : this.eventClickHandler.bind(this)

    });
    calendar.render();
  }

  getAllEvents() {
    getCalendarEvents()
      .then(result => {
        this.allEvents = result.map(item => {
          return {
            id : item.Id,
            editable : true,
            title : item.Title__c,
            start : item.Start_Date__c,
            end : item.End_Date__c,
            description : item.Description__c,
            allDay : false,
          };
        });
        this.initialiseFullCalendarJs();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(this.CALENDAR_ERROR_MESSAGE, error)
      });
  }
```

[**main.js**](https://github.com/bumerman/EventsCalendar/blob/main/main.js)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, is the Cache Control on `fullCalendar static resouce` set to public ?

Comment: Yes, fullCalendar static resouce set as public

Comment: Ah great, something else then. :) Have you also seen this question/answers: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/315612/4726, before v5 was not working even in LWC/aura and they were able to convert the fullcalendar to ES6 compatible module. So I am wondering if this still needs to be done in your case for communities/experience.

Comment: I did what was recommended there and FullCalendar started work inside the platform(Home Page, Record Page etc.), but it still doesn't work in Lightning Experience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was solved by disabling a "Lightning Locker" and switching "Content Security Policy (CSP) Security Level" to "Relaxed CSP" in the Experience Builder's Settings.
This is a temporary solution until we find out why the Lightning Locker blocks the FullCalendar library.[image: Locker location]